# what is meant by "appetite of fifteen" in Sense and Sensibility?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from the part of Sense and Sensibility where the Dashwood daughters moved to Barton Park.

> He [Mr.Middleton] was a blessing to all the juvenile part of the neighborhood, for in summer he was for ever forming parties to eat cold ham and chicken out of doors, and in winter his private balls were numerous enough for any young lady who was not suffering under the **insatiable appetite of fifteen**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jane Austen had a quick wit and much of her writing pokes fun at various groups of people.  In this case she implies that fifteen-year old ladies have an insatiable need for continual entertainment that no number of parties could satisfy.  I would assume Austen also means that young ladies grow out of this need as they grow up.

At that time perhaps fifteen was considered much more "adult" than it is today, considering that they were already courting and being courted, but otherwise I don't know that fifteen-year-olds have changed that much in their need for activity and stimulation.

Answer (score 0):

Read it as if "the insatiable appetite of (a person of) fifteen (years old)"